# If a class contains a certain name, change the style of that element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I currently have in my JS file:

```
if (documentElement.className("child") != -1){
    documentElement.className("child").backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Basically as the title implies, I want all the classes with the name "child" on the page to change their background color to red.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using CSS? since that would only require `.child { background-color: red }`

Comment: Can i add so the code only applies to a class within a class? example: `.parentclass{.child { background-color: red }}` @Roberrrt

Comment: Yes, you can, like `.parent .child { background-color: red }` < only selects .childs inside .parents

Answer (score 0):

`className` returns a string with all of the classes on the element. You need to see if that string contains your class:

```
if (documentElement.className.indexOf("child") != -1){
```

Use `indexOf`

Comment: Much better to use the `classList`, otherwise `childOfSomething` will also return true (and you probably don't want it...)

Comment: @Dekel -- Ahh yeah probably true, never thought of that ( seems like a bug I'd crowdsource out for user testing :D )

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what @Roberrrt said - you can achieve this simply selecting the 'child class' and applying a style to it.

For a visual example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNMJjr

In your code:

```
documentElement.className("child").backgroundColor="red";
```

That wouldn't work, this is a better way of achieving what you want:

```
document.querySelector('.child').style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

I still recommend using CSS. This is redundant and extremely verbose.

Comment: `.parentclass{
.child {
  background-color: red;
}
}`
 will this work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? No, that style wouldn't work.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.parentclass').querySelector('.child').style.backgroundColor = "red";`

this worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe (tested on *about:blank* page with 5 `<div>` with 2 of them with the `class="red"` :

```
var red = [];
red = document.querySelectorAll(".red");

for (var i = 0; i < red.length; i += 1) {
     red[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

If you really want to verify if the class name contains a string, use `classList.contains` (it often have resolved this kind of problem for me, check the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList))